# How do I fix this error 3734: Failed to add the foreign key constraint on MySQL WorkBench?

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-workbench

I am working on MySQL WorkBench and I keep getting error code 3734: Failed to add the foreign key constraint. What does this error mean and can I fix this error? I keep getting the error with the villa reservation table.

```
     create table Reservation
(
ReservationID char(5) primary key,
ReservationDate date,
CustomerID char(5),
foreign key (CustomerID) references Customer (CustomerID)
);

create table Villa
(
VillaID char(5) primary key,
VillaName varchar(40),
VillaCostPerDay int(3), 
VillaTypeID char(5),
foreign key (VillaTypeID) references VillaType (VillaTypeID)
);

``create table VillaReservation
    (
    VillaReservationID char(5),
    VillaID char(5),
    DateFrom datetime,
    DateTo datetime,
    primary key (VillaReservationID, VillaID),
    foreign key (VillaReservationID) references Reservation(VillaReservationID),
    foreign key (VillaID) references Villa(VillaID)
    );
```

Comment: Please show us the definition of your other two tables, by [edit]ing your question. They'll both need to be defined before you define this one.

Answer (score 0):

You are referencing the wrong column  `references Reservation(VillaReservationID)`
You have written `refer` Reservation but there's no column name `VillaReservationID`

```
primary key (VillaReservationID, VillaID),
foreign key (VillaReservationID) references Reservation(VillaReservationID)
```

you might have thought of `references Reservation(ReservationID)`
which is:

```
primary key (VillaReservationID, VillaID),
foreign key (VillaReservationID) references Reservation(ReservationID)
```